# Shorthand for if(true){doStuff()}?

Tags: javascript

Is there a shorter way to write the following if statement without using the hacky (at least 'less clear') methods outlined below?

```
if (isTireFlat){
  fixTire(); 
}
```

Short circuit:

```
isTireFlat && fixTire();
```

or

```
!isTireFlat || fixTire()
```

Ternary:

```
//not really usable due to return / useless variable assignment
return isTireFlat ? fixTire() : ''
```

Comment: I have to ask.  Why?

Comment: You've reduced it down to at most 3 lines and as few as 1. I'm not sure how much shorter you could want. If you could design your *own* shorthand, what would that even look like?

Comment: `fixTireIfFlat()`

Comment: @Paulpro lol fair. Archer - because short-circuits are unclear imo.

Comment: No - why do you want to not use the very first method that you posted?

Comment: I can, just wanted to see if there is a better way to do it, though I figured there wasn't, which is why I mentioned that I expected this to be downvoted to hell, though I think it was worth asking.

Comment: I believe you got all "sintactical" possibilities. The only option I would add is to "embed" the `if` and the method call into a single method, such as `ensureTiresAreOk()` or similar.

Comment: Fair enough.  I'm an advocate of readable and "safe" code and wouldn't consider doing anything other than a bog-standard `if` statement, complete with curly brackets, even if it was just a 1-liner.

Comment: @Archer Cool, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just about the only one you've left off is the braces-free `if`:

```
if (isTireFlat) fixTire();
```

Please note that this isn't intended as advocating doing it. Just pointing out the option that you didn't already have covered.

Comment: Linters don't like single line if statements without curly braces, which is why I am not doing it that way. But ty, makes sense.

Comment: @VSO You can configure your linter to prefer that style. ESLint does it very easily.

Comment: @VSO: Neither do I. :-) I prefer to just code the `if` (with braces); minification is for minifiers, not programmers. But that's *opinion*. ;-)